# Attaching and Detaching Fragments do not work on Xamarin Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have 3 tabs under my action bar and I want each menu to show different layouts. After researching for some time, I decided on making each tab fragment and using a FrameLayout as the container of Fragments. I prepared my fragments and tested each seperately and all 3 of my fragments works as intended. But my first approach was causing memory problems because I was not handling the transactions properly. After some more research I found out detaching and attaching is the best option. But when I wrote the detaching and attaching codes, it did not work. First fragment shows up on my screen, when I click on other tab, both detach and attach codes does nothing. The same screen stays on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
enum eLiveFragment{None,Feed,Articles,Promo}

    [Activity (Label = "Live",Theme = "@style/Theme.Discover")]         
    public class LiveActivity : Activity
    {
        FrameLayout contentLayout;
        //FragmentTransaction ft;

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        Fragment promoFrag;
        Fragment articleFrag;
        Fragment feedFrag;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LiveLayout);

            ActionBar.Title = Util.GetUIText (UILanguageText.LiveTBC_title);
            ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;       

            contentLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout> (Resource.Id.liveContent);

            fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
            fragmentTransaction.Commit();

            AddTab ("Promo", Resource.Drawable.live_icon_promos,eLiveFragment.Promo);
            AddTab ("Articles", Resource.Drawable.live_icon_articles,eLiveFragment.Articles);
            AddTab ("Feed", Resource.Drawable.live_icon_feed,eLiveFragment.Feed);
        }

        void AddTab (string tabText, int iconResourceId,eLiveFragment fragmentType  )
        {
            var tab = this.ActionBar.NewTab ();
            tab.SetCustomView (Resource.Layout.TabLayout);
            ImageView tabImageView = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.tabImage);
            TextView tabTextView = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tabText);
            tabImageView.SetImageResource (iconResourceId);
            tabTextView.Text = tabText;  

            tab.TabSelected += (sender, e) => {

                if (fragmentType == eLiveFragment.Promo) 
                {
                    if (promoFrag == null) 
                    {
                        promoFrag = Fragment.Instantiate(this, typeof(PromoGalleryFragment).Namespace.ToLower() + "." + typeof(PromoGalleryFragment).Name);
                        fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.liveContent, promoFrag, "Promo");
                    }
                    else
                        fragmentTransaction.Attach(promoFrag);
                }
                else if (fragmentType == eLiveFragment.Articles) 
                {
                    if (articleFrag == null) 
                    {
                        articleFrag = Fragment.Instantiate(this, typeof(ArticleFragment).Namespace.ToLower() + "." + typeof(ArticleFragment).Name);
                        fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.liveContent, articleFrag, "Article");
                    }
                    else
                        fragmentTransaction.Attach(articleFrag);
                }
                else if (fragmentType == eLiveFragment.Feed) 
                {
                    if (promoFrag == null) 
                    {
                        feedFrag = Fragment.Instantiate(this, typeof(FeedFragment).Namespace.ToLower() + "." + typeof(FeedFragment).Name);
                        fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.liveContent, feedFrag, "Feed");
                    }
                    else
                        fragmentTransaction.Attach(feedFrag);
                }

            };

            tab.TabUnselected += (sender, e) => {
                if (fragmentType == eLiveFragment.Promo) 
                {
                    fragmentTransaction.Detach(FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("Promo"));
                }
                else if (fragmentType == eLiveFragment.Articles) 
                {
                    fragmentTransaction.Detach(FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("Article"));
                }
                else if (fragmentType == eLiveFragment.Feed) 
                {
                    fragmentTransaction.Detach(FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("Feed"));
                }
            };
            this.ActionBar.AddTab (tab);
        }
    }
```

And here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/liveContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also I used breakpoints to see if the unselected and selected events works properly, and they do. Attach and detach codes works but does nothing.

Comment: I don't see anywhere, where you call `Commit()` on the `FragmentTransaction` after `Attach()` or `Detach()`.

Comment: When I commited once and try to commit again application crashes and says you already committed.

Comment: When I commit a fragment transaction and after a change try to commit again I get an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too late to answer your question. But I found a solution to your problem. 
You have to call

```
fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
```

before doing any transaction on fragment. Make sure to order fragmentTransaction.commit() correctly so that it is not called repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AddTab` method is not invoked inside your fragment transaction. See an updated `OnCreate` below.

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.LiveLayout);

        ActionBar.Title = Util.GetUIText (UILanguageText.LiveTBC_title);
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;       

        contentLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout> (Resource.Id.liveContent);

        fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
        AddTab ("Promo", Resource.Drawable.live_icon_promos,eLiveFragment.Promo);
        AddTab ("Articles", Resource.Drawable.live_icon_articles,eLiveFragment.Articles);
        AddTab ("Feed", Resource.Drawable.live_icon_feed,eLiveFragment.Feed);
        fragmentTransaction.Commit();
    }
```